# How to create a drop down menu form containing all the databases stored in mysql using PHP?

Tags: php, sql

php

```
$db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','Password');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES"); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
echo $row[0]."<br>";
```

}

So far I have used the following lines to display the databases on my webpage. But i need to show the databases in the form of a drop down menu

Comment: You could use [a Bootstrap dropdown](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/).

Answer (score 1):

not sure how you structured your database and HTML, but you need to add a `<select>` element in your page and loop your result as options for this select

Example

```
<?php

$db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','Password');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES");
?>
<select>
<?php 
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
    echo "<option>{$row[0]}</option>"; 
  }
?>
</select>
```

I hope you got the idea

Comment: @varadjunnarkar you most welcome

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to this problem is to wrap your result in a list. of course, dropdowns are always in a list... so on your dropdown menu, find the list and iterate through the list of databases like the one below.

```
<?php

$db_conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','Password');
$result = mysqli_query($db_conn,"SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
?>

<li> <?php echo $row[0]; ?> </li>

<?php
}

?>
```